# substring extraction in Mysql

Tags: mysql, substring

I have some ISBN data in the field `description`, the data is formatted like so ISBN:10 (ten digit ISBN number) , the string in the field description is not patterned, for example, it can appear like this

(author name text) (custom name text) ISBN:10 (isbn number) (some other data text) or also like this with just the isbn number
ISBN:10 (isbn number) and so on.

I have tried the following LOCATE mysql statement, but this turns out irregular data as it removes some numbers from the ISBN number

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(database.description, 
      LOCATE('ISBN10:', auctions.description)+8) 

    AS ISBn_number
FROM 
    database_books AS database
```

Comment: Thats why db normalization is useful.

Comment: Can you post an example row where it removes some numbers?  Which numbers (beginning, end?)  Is there always a space after ISBN10:?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each of your isbns is really included in the description in the format

`ISBN:10<space>0123456789<space>`

and you can select all the dataset with the where clause

```
where description like '%ISBN:10 __________ %'
```

then you can extract all the ISBNs with:

```
select SUBSTRING(description,LOCATE('ISBN:10 ',description)+8,10 ) isbn10 
from database_books
where description like '%ISBN:10 __________ %'
```

- Note1: It appears that you try to select from 2 different tables 'database' and 'auctions'.
- Note2: I wouldn't recommend to call a table 'database'.
- Note3: I wouldn't recommend that you create an auction house software ;) (joke)